# Looking for mpic++

Tags: boost, openmpi, mpich, boost-mpi, mpic++

I am following [these instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html#mpi.config) trying to build Boost MPI `.lib` files, but I encountered one problem: I do not have `mpic++`.

Looking at the MPI implementation files such as MPICH and Open MPI, I see no `mpic++` included at all.

Where can I find `mpic++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your distribution or OS?

My Debian / Ubuntu systems have it as a softlink to `mpic++.openmpi` (which comes from the libopenmpi-dev package). So I use Open MPI; the MPICH2 packages provide the same softlink.

Comment: I am using WinXP with Visual Studios Express 2008.

Comment: Well then you will have to check your OpenMPI or MPICh2 installation as to whether (and if so, where) it provides an `mpic++` binary.

Answer (score 3):

MPICH2 uses "mpicxx" as its C++ compiler wrapper name.